# why this snipped code triggers breakpoint at second iteration at this line "*(str_arr + i) = (char*)calloc((strlen(temp_str) + 1), sizeof(char));"

Tags: c, visual-studio

Just trying to scan `N` strings to an array and dynamically allocate them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3
#define MAX_STR_LEN 20

void main(void) {
    char* str_arr[N] = { '\0' };
    char temp_str[MAX_STR_LEN] = { '\0' };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //scan string
        fgets(temp_str, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
        strtok(temp_str, "\n");

        // next line of code triggers breakpoint at second iteration
        *(str_arr + i) = (char*)calloc((strlen(temp_str) + 1), sizeof(char));
        if (!(str_arr + i))
        {
            printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //copy temporary string to dedicated string
        strcpy_s(*(str_arr + i), sizeof(temp_str), temp_str);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Not seeing much in the way of C++ here. Which language are you compiling it as? Pick one please.

Comment: You're lying to `strcpy_s` about the size of the buffer pointed to by `str_arr[i]`.

Comment: And the type of first argument to `strcpy_s` is?..

Comment: compiled as C, sorry for the mistaken tag

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

- You didn't allocate `sizeof(temp_str)`. You allocated
  `strlen(temp_str)+1`. So the first `strcpy_s` is going to cause a buffer overrun, which is why things go bad on the second iteration through the loop.
- The statement `if (!(str_arr +i))` doesn't check the pointer that you
  just allocated
- `*(str_arr + i)` is the same as `str_arr[i]` and the latter is easier
  for someone reading the code
- In the line `char* str_arr[N] = { '\0' };`, you declare an array of pointers, but you initialize with a character constant (`\0`) which is an `int`. The initializer should be a `NULL` pointer.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109) shows a better way to remove the newline from the buffer. The problem with `strtok` is that it won't remove the newline if/when the user enters a blank line.

With that in mind, here's my recommended fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3
#define MAX_STR_LEN 20

int main(void) {
    char* str_arr[N] = { NULL };
    char temp_str[MAX_STR_LEN] = { '\0' };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //scan string
        if (fgets(temp_str, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin) == NULL)
        { 
            printf("Not enough lines of input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        temp_str[strcspn(temp_str, "\n")] = '\0';

        size_t length = strlen(temp_str) + 1;
        str_arr[i] = (char *)calloc(length, 1);
        if (!str_arr[i])
        {
            printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //copy temporary string to dedicated string
        strcpy_s(str_arr[i], length, temp_str);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: OP used “char* str_arr[N] = { '\0' };” and you change it to “char* str_arr[N] = { NULL };”. Maybe you want to explain to the OP, why you did that.

Comment: Although ignoring the return of `strtok` works for this specific case, it might be better to utilize it and explain [to OP] why that's better for the general case

Comment: Re bullet 4: Integer 0 is freely convertible to the NULL pointer and back.

Comment: @user58697 And if you turn the warnings up, you get *"warning: expression which evaluates to zero treated as a null
      pointer constant of type 'char *' [-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]"*. So yes, you can do that, but you shouldn't.